# Android Studio error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified ..... Android 12

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debugging

I started programming with AndroidStudio today and a friend sent me a small sample app but I can't run any code because this error keeps coming up. I've been trying to solve it for about 3 hours now with different forums but I can't get it to work I would be very grateful for your help because I just don't know what to do....

Console:

````
    android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#com.dbestech.food_delivery.MainActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#com.dbestech.food_delivery.MainActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
___________________________________________________________________________________

and my AndroidManifest.xml file:

___________________________________________________________________________________

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dbestech.food_delivery">
    <!-- Flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>```
````

Comment: added `android:exported="true"` to your launcher activity or with `intent-launcher` in manifest

Comment: tyyyyyyy !!!!!!!

Comment: hey check the answer with more details!

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

You need to find `<activity>` tag with `intent-filter` with `action` **MAIN** and `category` with **LAUNCHER**

and add `android:exported="true"` like this -

```
 <activity
   android:name=".MainActivity"
   android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```